# classx does not implement the requested interface classx, libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to use the setView() method for the OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer class in libgdx but I keep getting following error message:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException:
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch does not implement the
>   requested interface com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch does not implement the
>   requested interface com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.BatchTiledMapRenderer.setView(BatchTiledMapRenderer.java:91)
>     at com.nick.seperate.states.Play.render(Play.java:100)  at
>   com.nick.seperate.handlers.GameStateManager.render(GameStateManager.java:32)
>     at com.nick.seperate.Seperate.render(Seperate.java:58)  at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:187)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)

What doesn't make sense to me is that I looked at the code for the com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch class and it DOES implement the Batch class.

If posting some code will help, just ask but I don't see how it would be helpful.

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward: `Class com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch does not implement the requested interface com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch`

Comment: I said in the post that I checked and it DOES implement it.

Comment: Which libgdx version do you use? How did you create the project? Are you sure that all natives and .jar files fit together in all projects?

Comment: I used the gdx-setup-ui.jar and I downloaded the latest stable version. I just let the setup program create the projects and stuff.

Comment: The gdx-setup-ui is outdated. You should use gdx-setup now. It uses the gradle buildsystem.

Comment: Well, if you checked and it *does* implement it - you should have no problem *shrug* (without seeing the code we can sit here all day and keep guessing...)

Comment: @noone is right, gdx-setup-ui won't work with the latest libgdx versions, you should now use: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle